# TYPO3 11.5.2 static template "site package" not showing up

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, typo3-11.x

TYPO3 11.5.2

I'm following the TYPO3 Sitepackage Tutorial.

At the topic [Extension installation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/11.5/en-us/ExtensionInstallation/Index.html) I can't solve the issue that the static template "site package" does not show up in "Available Items" list.

TL;DR: solution: access rights to the extensions folder were wrong for apache/php to read.

The extension is installed via composer and visible:
[image: Screenshot Extension Manager]

But no static template to pick:
[image: Screenshot Template editing]

I actually did the whole process twice, the first time I changed the site package source, which I downloaded from [github](https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Tutorial-SitePackage-Code) , to have our local names, so I thought, ok I did it wrong. The second attempt I didn't change anything but with the same result.

And idea how I can find out what's happening or why the desired result is not happening?

Why can't I pick the site package static template?

I found something which may lead to a solution:
When I do "Admin Tools -> Upgrade -> Scan Extension Files" I get an error for extension "site package":

> (1/1) #1499777330 RuntimeException
> Extension path /var/www/html/typo3_11/public/typo3conf/ext/site_package does not exist or is no directory.

which comes from

```
in /var/www/html/typo3_11/public/typo3/sysext/install/Classes/Controller/UpgradeController.php line 681
            1499777261
        );
    }
    if (!is_dir($extensionBasePath)) {
        throw new \RuntimeException(
            'Extension path ' . $extensionBasePath . ' does not exist or is no directory.',
            1499777330
        );
    }
```

The reason is clear, because it's not a directory but a symbolic link to ../../../local_packages/site_package

which is the recommended way. So this may be not related to the issue that the static template doesn't show in the "Availabe items" list, but perhaps it helps to find the real reason.

Removing the symbolic link and moving folder "site package" from local_packages to typo3conf/ext resolves the issue, the static template "site package" is available in "Available items". This doesn't seem to be a viable solution because of the recommended way this should be installed via composer. Or perhaps there is something wrong in the composer installation?

Comment: Thats an composer thing. Composer allowed different locations where it can load packages from. pagagist.org of course, github, a few more options and one interesting one, from your local file system. In this case it just creates an symlink to this local folder. This folder can even be outside your web-root. But maybe this is also the reason why it breaks. file/folder rights or the right to symlink to your source folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be available there with [this code](https://github.com/TYPO3-Documentation/TYPO3CMS-Tutorial-SitePackage-Code/blob/master/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_template.php) ([manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/tutorial-sitepackage/master/en-us/ExtensionConfiguration/Index.html#make-typoscript-available)).

After clearing system caches, I would expect it to show up.

Comment: Thank you for your answer: Yes, the code is present in the local extension. I did flush the cache, did it again now, but without success, it still doesn't show up.

Comment: Oh, you have added that exception you get "RuntimeException Extension path /var/www/html/typo3_11/public/typo3conf/ext/site_package does not exist or is no directory." - that means that composer hasn't properly copied/symlinked your extension. I would try a `composer rem vendor/your-ext; composer req vendor/your-ext` to force a reinstall.

Comment: btw. symlink or directory has always been fine there and is recommended. I'll check later with a current v11 and the site package tutorial if I can reproduce.

Comment: As you suggested I did a "composer remove" and "composer require" again, with the same result. All seems to be fine installed except for the static template is missing. As described in the last edit, removing symbolic link and moving it into typo3conf/ext makes the static template available. I am looking forward to your results, thanks in advance for your efforts!

Comment: I found the embarrassing reason: folder local_packages had wrong ownership, php couldn't access the folder. Sorry, but many thanks for your help.

Comment: Great that it worked out. Happy weekend!

Comment: Could someone approve my edit of the answer? Currently it doesn't make too much sense as solution. @peter-kraume